# Model Override issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, model, newsletter

I have issue in Override the  Newsletter Queue Model  to sent Newsletter Based on Specific Customer group. But, It throw

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Registry, array given, called in /var/www/public/app/code/vendor/Module/Model/Queue.php on line 26 and defined in /var/www/public/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue.php:125

what i did :

create `di.xml`:

add below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
        <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue" type="vendor\Module\Model\Queue" />
    </config>
```

Create `Vendor/Module/Model/Queue`:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface;



class Queue extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue
{

    protected $_customergroup;
    protected $_customergroupdata;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customergroupdata,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
        $this->_customergroup = $customergroup;
        $this->_customergroupdata = $customergroupdata;
    }

    public function sendPerSubscriber($count = 20)
    {
        if ($this->getQueueStatus() != self::STATUS_SENDING &&
            ($this->getQueueStatus() != self::STATUS_NEVER &&
                $this->getQueueStartAt())
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_subscribersCollection->getQueueJoinedFlag()) {
            $this->_subscribersCollection->useQueue($this);
        }

        if ($this->_subscribersCollection->getSize() == 0) {
            $this->_finishQueue();
            return $this;
        }

        $collection = $this->_subscribersCollection->useOnlyUnsent()->showCustomerInfo()->setPageSize(
            $count
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        )->load();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateData(
            [
                'template_subject' => $this->getNewsletterSubject(),
                'template_text' => $this->getNewsletterText(),
                'template_styles' => $this->getNewsletterStyles(),
                'template_filter' => $this->_templateFilter,
                'template_type' => self::TYPE_HTML,
            ]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $item */
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {

            //MY customized code:

            //  var_dump($this->_customergroup->getCustomersbyGroup(4));

            $groupOptions = $this->_customergroupdata->toOptionArray();

            $groups = array();
            //$groupid=array();

            foreach ($groupOptions as $group) {
                array_push($groups, $group["label"]);

            }
            foreach ($groups as $groupname) {
                if ($groupname = "Daily customers") {

                    $groupid = $groupOptions["value"];

                    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions(
                        ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $item->getStoreId()]
                    )->setTemplateVars(
                        ['subscriber' => $item]
                    )->setFrom(
                        ['name' => $this->getNewsletterSenderName(), 'email' => $this->getNewsletterSenderEmail()]
                    )->addTo(
                    //$item->getSubscriberEmail(),
                    //$item->getSubscriberFullName()
                        $this->_customergroup->getCustomersbyGroup($groupid)
                    )->getTransport();

                    try {
                        $transport->sendMessage();
                    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException $e) {
                        /** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Problem $problem */
                        $problem = $this->_problemFactory->create();
                        $problem->addSubscriberData($item);
                        $problem->addQueueData($this);
                        $problem->addErrorData($e);
                        $problem->save();
                    }
                    $item->received($this);
                }

                if (count($collection->getItems()) < $count - 1 || count($collection->getItems()) == 0) {
                    $this->_finishQueue();
                }
                return parent::sendPerSubscriber();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And I add One Block in contractor for dependency injection    `\Vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup` i am not write this path to `di.xml`. I am directly inserted in this code.

is there any probelm?

**Edit:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73 
>   Suggest Me What I miss in my code, how to Solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Per @Paul Suggestion, I move my dependencies above Abstatct class

This is My Dependencies:

> \Vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup,
>
> \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customergroupdata,

Move to Above Abstack class:

```
  \vendort\module\Block\Testing $customergroup,
   \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customergroupdata,
  \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
  \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
```

And Also Order the Paramenter:

```
      parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $registry,
                $templateFilter,
                $date,
                $templateFactory,
                $problemFactory,
                $subscriberCollectionFactory,
                $transportBuilder,
                $resource,
                $resourceCollection,
                $data
            );
```

My Final Code:

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template\Filter $templateFilter,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\TemplateFactory $templateFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ProblemFactory $problemFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customergroupdata,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_templateFilter = $templateFilter;
    $this->_date = $date;
    $this->_templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    $this->_problemFactory = $problemFactory;
    $this->_subscribersCollection = $subscriberCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_customergroup =$customergroup;
    $this->_customergroupdata=$customergroupdata;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $templateFilter,
        $date,
        $templateFactory,
        $problemFactory,
        $subscriberCollectionFactory,
        $transportBuilder,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
}
```

Its Works for Me, I think magento2 Need Some Order wise Objects paramenter.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by the fact that your model constructor does not match your original model constructor.

So this is the constructor from `Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue` :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template\Filter $templateFilter,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\TemplateFactory $templateFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ProblemFactory $problemFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
    $this->_templateFilter = $templateFilter;
    $this->_date = $date;
    $this->_templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    $this->_problemFactory = $problemFactory;
    $this->_subscribersCollection = $subscriberCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
}
```

To fix your constructor it needs to be:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template\Filter $templateFilter,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\TemplateFactory $templateFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ProblemFactory $problemFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    \Vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customergroupdata,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_customergroup = $customergroup;
    $this->_customergroupdata = $customergroupdata;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $templateFilter,
        $date,
        $templateFactory,
        $problemFactory,
        $subscriberCollectionFactory,
        $transportBuilder,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
}
```

Comment: I add your suggest then throw error, check my edit question.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E which Magento version are you running ?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.0.8

Comment: @Rajkumar.E I made a typo, try with my updated code

Comment: you change " $subscriberCollection," to " $subscriberCollectionFactory," right?

Comment: I already change this?

Comment: Yes that's what I changed

Comment: @Rajkumar.E also delete var/di var/cache and var/generation

Comment: still same problem...   can i add block in contractor for DI , is there any problem.`\Vendor\Module\Block\Testing $customergroup,`

Comment: @Rajkumar.E in theory yes you can but I'm not sure why you would do that

Comment: @I write some common function in this block, so I need to use this in this model.

Comment: you should write those function in a helper if those functions are also used in a model, not in a block

Comment: ok, suggest me What are the reason throw  this error `Cannot instantiate abstract class` in magento 2.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E honestly I don't know I've never seen that, must be an issue with the rest of your code I reckon

Comment: Try moving the dependencies that you need above the two abstract classes in the constructor.